# How can i lock a MUTEX for an element in the array, not for the complete array

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Short version of the question: I have 2 functions that share the same array, when one is editing it, the other is reading it. However, the vector is long (5000 samples) and concurrent access rarely happens. but the Mutex contention on `MUTEX1` is slowing down the program. '

How can I lock certain locations of the memory instead of the complete block in order to reduce contention?

EDIT: Note: I have to use updated G values whenever possible.

EDIT2:  For example I have array G of length 5000. `foo1` locks `mutex1` to edit index 124.  Although `foo2` wants to edit index 2349, it cannot until `foo1` releases `mutex1`.

is there a way I can move the contention of locking a mutex down to the element level? meaning: I want `foo2` and `foo1` to only contest on a the same mutex, only when they want to edit the same index. E.g: `foo1` wants to edit index 3156, and `foo2` wants to edit index 3156.

Long version with code explanation: 
I am writing a code for a complex mathematical function,  and I am using pthreads to parallel the code and enhance the performance. The code is very complex and I can post it but I can post a model to the code.

Basically I have 2 arrays that I want to edit using 2 threads that run in parallel. One thread runs `foo1` and the other runs `foo2`.  However, they should run in a particular sequence and I use `mutex`es(`_B`,`_A1`, and `_A2`) to grantee the sequence. it goes as follows :

```
foo1 (first half)
foo2 (first half) and foo1 (second half) (in parallel)
foo1 (first half) and foo2 (second half) (in parallel)
...
foo2(second half)
```

then I would retrieve my results.
In the first half of `foo1` I will be using results in `G1` that is might be edited at the same time by `foo2`.  Therefore I use `Mutex1` to protect it. same happens in `foo2` for `G`.  However, locking the complete vector for 1 value is very in efficient, they nearly never edit the same memory location at the same time. when I compare the results, it is almost always the same. I would like a way to lock one element at a time, so that they only contest the same element.

I will describe the code for people interested to know how it works:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define numThreads 2
#define Length 10000

pthread_t threads[numThreads];

pthread_mutex_t mutex1   = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t Mutex_B  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t Mutex_A1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t Mutex_A2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct data_pointers
{
    double  *A;
    double  *B;
    double  *G;
    double  *L;
    int idxThread;
};

void foo1   (data_pointers &data);
void foo2   (data_pointers &data);

void *thread_func(void *arg){
    data_pointers data = *((data_pointers *) arg);
    if (data.idxThread==0)
        foo1 (data);
    else
        foo2 (data);
}
```

Up to here it is definitions and thread calling function, bare in mind that I define `Length 10000` and `numThreads 2`

```
void foo1 ( data_pointers &data)
{
    double *A           = data.A;
    double *L           = data.L; 
    double *G           = data.G; 
    double U;

    for (int ijk =0;ijk<5;ijk++){
        /* here goes some definitions*/

        pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex_A1);

        for (int k =0;k<Length;k++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); 
            U = G[k];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
            /*U undergoes a lot of mathematical operations here


            */
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex_B);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_A2);
        for (int k =0;k<Length;k++){
            /*U another mathematical operations here


            */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
            L[k] = U;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_B);
        }
    }
}
```

in foo1 I lock `mutexA1` and complete my work,  then I lock `MutexB` and unlock `MutexA2` so `foo2` can start working. Note that `main` starts by locking `MutexA2`. This way I garantee `foo1` started second half with `mutexB` locked, this way, `foo2` cannot enter the second half of the function until `foo1` unlocks `mutexB`

```
void foo2 (data_pointers &data)
{
    double *A           = data.A;
    double *L           = data.L; 
    double *G           = data.G; 
    double U;

    for (int ijk =0;ijk<5;ijk++){
        /* here goes some definitions*/

        pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex_A1);

        for (int k =0;k<Length;k++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); 
            U = G[k];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
            /*U undergoes a lot of mathematical operations here


            */
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex_B);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_A2);
        for (int k =0;k<Length;k++){        
            /*U another mathematical operations here


            */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
            L[k] = U;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_B);

        }
    }
}
```

Now, when `foo1` unlocks `mutexB` it will have to wait for `foo2` to unlock `mutexA1` so it can work, `foo2` will only unlock `mutexA2` when it already unlocked `mutexB`.

this goes on and on 5 times.

```
int main(){
    double G1[Length];
    double G2[Length];
    double B1[Length];
    double B2[Length];
    double A2[Length];
    double A1[Length];
    data_pointers data[numThreads];

    data[0].L           = G2;
    data[0].G           = G1;   
    data[0].A           = A1;
    data[0].B           = B1;
    data[0].idxThread   = 0;

    data[1].L           = G1;
    data[1].G           = G2;   
    data[1].A           = A2;
    data[1].B           = B2;
    data[1].idxThread   = 1;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex_A2);

    pthread_create(&(threads[0]), NULL, thread_func, (void *) &(data[0]));
    pthread_create(&(threads[1]), NULL, thread_func, (void *) &(data[1]));
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_A1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex_A2);

    return 0;
}
```

note this is only an example code. compiles and works as intended, but with no output.

LAST EDIT:  Thank you all for the great ideas, I had a lot of experience, and fun following those suggestions. I will up vote all answers as they were useful, and pick the closest to the original question (atomicity)

Comment: vector of pairs of doubles and mutexes?

Comment: @Joe can you elaborate more? I didn't understand. but note that the updated values must be used.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that if you only want to lock a specific element you need a lock for each element. So you could have pairs of locks and doubles, allowing you to lock each double individually. Though the real win is to come with an algorithm that guarantees the two threads never need simultaneous access to the same element.

Comment: Actually in my code, if I am editing an odd index, only other indecies are in danger of concurrent editing, so I can create 2 mutexes. but the problem is that an if statement is going to be way more slower than the mutex case.

Comment: So if you have an odd even access pattern could you sort them and get each thread to approach from opposite ends?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think your question is hard to understand. The short version leaves the impression that you want to protect the element one-by-one. The long version leaves the impression that you want to control how two threads executes. If your problem is "just" the element-by-element protection, you should read about compare-and-swap.

Comment: I just tried the mutex on odd and even indexes, same degradation. I cannot do that because inside each foo, index n is dependent on index n-1,  so I cannot split them to 2 odd and even foo's.

Comment: @StillLearning lets say I lock mutex1 because I am editing index 50, and foo2 wants to update index 100, it will still wait for the mutex although it does not need it.

Comment: Does the size of your arrays ever change?

Comment: Read about compare-and-swap. It allows for lock-free data structures, i.e. multiple threads can access (read/write) the same array of data-structures with out using a mutex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: @bku_drytt no. stilllearning, thanks I will do, although I have no clue about data structures lol!

Comment: You can try using an atomic pointer for whichever element is being edited by your editor thread, in your processing(reader) thread, you check that pointer to see if it's in use or not. This allows you to process/read any element that isn't currently being edited. There is an issue in that your processing thread will block for all elements past the element currently being edited if your processing is done quicker than your editing and you start processing from an element that comes before the one you're currently editing. I'll try coming up with a solution once I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code of using an atomic pointer to 'lock' certain locations in memory:

```
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

using container = std::vector<std::atomic<double>>;
using container_size_type = container::size_type;

container c(300);

std::atomic<container::pointer> p_busy_elem{ nullptr };

void editor()
{
    for (container_size_type i{ 0 }, sz{ c.size() }; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        p_busy_elem.exchange(&c[i]); // c[i] is busy
        // ... edit c[i] ... // E: calculate a value and assign it to c[i]
        p_busy_elem.exchange(nullptr); // c[i] is no longer busy
    }
}

void reader()
{
    for (container_size_type i{ 0 }, sz{ c.size() }; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        // A1: wait for editor thread to finish editing value
        while (p_busy_elem == &c[i])
        {
            // A2: room a better algorithm to prevent blocking/yielding
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }

        // B: if c[i] is updated in between A and B, this will load the latest value
        auto value = c[i].load();

        // C: c[i] might have changed by this time, but we had the most up to date value we could get without checking again
        // ... use value ...
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t_editor{ editor };
    std::thread t_reader{ reader };
    t_editor.join();
    t_reader.join();
}
```

In the editor thread, the busy pointer is set to indicate that that memory location is currently being edited (**E**). If thread B attempts to read that value after the busy pointer is set, it will wait until the editing is done before proceeding (**A1**).

Note on **A2**: A better system could be placed here. A list of nodes that were busy when a read was attempted could be kept, we would then add `i` to that list and attempt to process the list at a later time. Benefit: the loop could be told to execute a `continue` and indices past the currently being edited `i` would be read.

A copy of the value to read is made (**B**) in order to use it (**C**) however needed. This is the last time we can check for the latest value at `c[i]`.

Comment: Made this pretty quickly, might have to edit it. Anyone who notices issues is very welcome to point them out!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not resize your arrays, you do not need any mutexes on individual elements or whole array.

Read your values atomically, write your values atomically and stay calm.

Comment: Yes I don't resize the arrays. Can you please elaborate more? why don't I need a mutex? what if the two threads try to edit the same index at the same time?  and do I insure atomicity using a an atomic pointer?

Comment: If two threads try to edit an atomic value at once, then one of them will either get it first or second, there will be no data race (both getting it at once), as that is what atomicity guarantees. As for my comment in your original post, you can also have a list that keeps track of values that could not be processed/written to because they were being used by a thread and process that list at some point (I'd have to think more about when the best time would be).

Comment: @user304584, the reader will get 'valid' value - meaning, it will not be dirty-written, it will be either the one just before the update, or right after. On any rate, this value should be good for you.

Comment: To add to what @SergeyA is saying, using mutexes is already giving you a similar behavior: you are either getting the one before the update or the one after, except that you are blocking access for the whole array. That issue is solved by atomic stores and loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you want high-performance multi-thread access to an array-like data structure without using mutex, you could investigate compare-and-swap. Maybe you can design a lock-free data structure that will work for your specific problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Regarding the posted code, it seems you are complicating matters a bit too much. If you want to achieve:

```
foo1 (first half)
foo2 (first half) and foo1 (second half) (in parallel)
foo1 (first half) and foo2 (second half) (in parallel)
...
foo2(second half)
```

two mutxes should do.

Maybe this could do. Some pseudo-code below:

```
// These global variables controls which thread is allowed to
// execute first and second half.
// 1 --> Foo1 may run
// 2 --> Foo2 may run
int accessFirstHalf = 1;
int accessSecondHalf = 1;

void foo1 ( data_pointers &data)
{
    while(YOU_LIKE_TO_GO_ON)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TAKE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
            if (accessFirstHalf == 1)
            {
                RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
                break;
            }
            RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
            pthread_yield();
        }

        // Do the first half

        TAKE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
        // Allow Foo2 to do first half
        accessFirstHalf == 2;
        RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;

        while (true)
        {
            TAKE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
            if (accessSecondHalf == 1)
            {
                RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
                break;
            }
            RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
            pthread_yield();
        }

        // Do the second half

        TAKE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
        // Allow Foo2 to do second half
        accessSecondHalf == 2;
        RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
    }
}


void foo2 ( data_pointers &data)
{
    while(YOU_LIKE_TO_GO_ON)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TAKE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
            if (accessFirstHalf == 2)
            {
                RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
                break;
            }
            RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
            pthread_yield();
        }

        // Do the first half

        TAKE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;
        // Allow Foo1 to do first half
        accessFirstHalf == 1;
        RELEASE_MUTEX_FIRST_HALF;

        while (true)
        {
            TAKE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
            if (accessSecondHalf == 2)
            {
                RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
                break;
            }
            RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
            pthread_yield();
        }

        // Do the second half

        TAKE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
        // Allow Foo1 to do second half
        accessSecondHalf == 1;
        RELEASE_MUTEX_SECOND_HALF;
    }
}


int main()
{
    // start the threads with foo1 and foo2
}
```

Comment: That was my initial design.  But I discovered that thread 1 might lock and unlock the first and second halves mutexes, then, mutexes will start doing it work, which is not synchronized. and thats why I came up with the 3 mutex strategy.  Also, I did this to avoid using a thread pool, or having to call pthread_create a lot.

Comment: I realized my first answer were wrong. This is hopefully better. Added yield so that the waiting thread allows the other thread access to the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the heart of your requirement:

> ```
> foo1 (first half)
> foo2 (first half) and foo1 (second half) (in parallel)
> foo1 (first half) and foo2 (second half) (in parallel)
> ...
> foo2(second half)
> ```

The easiest way to achieve this interleaving with pthreads is to use barriers.

Initialise a barrier with `pthread_barrier_init()` using a `count` of 2.  `foo1()` then executes:

```
first half
pthread_barrier_wait()
second half
pthread_barrier_wait()
...
first half
pthread_barrier_wait()
second half
pthread_barrier_wait()
```

and `foo2()` executes a slightly different sequence:

```
pthread_barrier_wait()
first half
pthread_barrier_wait()
second half
....
pthread_barrier_wait()
first half
pthread_barrier_wait()
second half
```